# How to insert dropdown into dynamic table in angular7

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

Tried to insert dropdown inside dynamic table but i do not know how to do it.I want to insert dropdown with some values on last column.Please help anyone to find the solution.

```
  head = [   "Name",  "Age", "Gender","Action"]; 

  details = [ 
            { "name": "star1", "age": "25", "gender": "male","action": "" }, 
             { "name": "star2", "age": "22", "gender": "female","action": "" },
            { "name": "star3", "age": "21", "gender": "male","action": "" },
             { "name": "star4", "age": "35", "gender": "female","action": "" },
        ]; 

  constructor(){
      this.tableHead = this.head; 
      this.userDetails = this.details;
  }
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfs3gp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution for you. Can you please replace your details array to

```
details = [
      { name: "star1", age: "25", gender: "male", action: ["Edit", "Delete"] },
      { name: "star2", age: "22", gender: "female", action: ["Edit", "Delete"] },
      { name: "star3", age: "21", gender: "male", action: ["Edit", "Delete"] },
      { name: "star4", age: "35", gender: "female", action: ["Edit", "Delete"] }
];
```

Then Replace the **dynamic-table.component.html** to below code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-head">
      <th *ngFor="let tableHead of tableHeads">{{tableHead}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tableData of tableDatas">
      <td *ngFor="let colName of tableColNameGenerated"> {{colName != 'action' ? tableData[colName] : ''}}
        <span *ngIf="colName == 'action'">
          <select>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of tableData.action">{{opt}}</option>
          </select>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I hope your concern is resolved.
Hope this helps!
Thank you.